# Смысл фразы "Инструкция присваивания создаёт ссылку на объект"

Tags: python

Сейчас изучаю python по книжке Марка Лутца. И там в главе 11 рассматривается инструкция присваивания. И у меня возникла некоторые непонимание. В книжке пишется.

> **Инструкция присваивания создаёт ссылку на объект**. Как говорилось в главе 6, в языке Python инструкция присваивания сохраняет ссылки на объекты в переменных или элементах структур данных. Они всегда созадают ссылки на объекты и никогда не создают копии объектов. Вследствие этого переменные в языке Python больше напоминают указатели, чем области хранения данных.

Но вот контрпример, если касаться списков:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a = a + a
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Как видно b не изменился, значит в этой операции >>> b = a была создана копия a, а не b присвоен указатель на a.

То же самое и здесь:

```
>>> k = 10
>>> l = k
>>> k = 20
>>> k
20
>>> l
10
```

Я, видимо, что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Вот [рисунки, которые хорошо показывают разницу между "областями хранения"  в некоторых языках и именах ("ссылки:указатели") в Питоне](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все станет очевидней, если добавить "id()" в Ваш пример

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> id(a)
14342744
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
14342744
>>> a = a + a
>>> id(a)
14342424
>>> id(b)
14342744
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
```

Когда Вы делаете "a = a + a", то **создается новый объект** "a + a" ([1,2,3] + [1,2,3]) и ссылка на него присваивается переменной "а", однако объект [1,2,3] никуда не теряется т.к. b продолжает ссылаться на него.

То же самое для второго примера, сначала k ссылается на объект типа int со значением 10, который лежит где-то-там-глубоко-в-памяти-интерпретатора, l ссылается не на k, а на тот же объект-который-далеко-в-памяти. Операция "k = 20" означает "создать в памяти объект int со значением 20 и ссылку на него присвоить переменной k", однако l продолжает ссылаться на первый int'овый объект со значением 10.

Можно ещё добавить, что во многих случаях, если объект с требуемым значением уже был создан, то ещё один такой же объект создаваться не будет, и переменная будет содержать уже ссылку на ранее созданный объект.

Comment: очень так подробно объяснили. Спасибо. Сразу всё понятно стало.

Comment: "Можно ещё добавить, что во многих случаях, если объект с требуемым значением уже был создан, то ещё один такой же объект создаваться не будет, и переменная будет содержать уже ссылку на ранее созданный объект."
это получается как оптимизация идёт. так?

Comment: Да, именно оптимизация.
Посмотрите на такой код:
>>> s1 = "123123123"
>>> s2 = "123123123"
>>> id(s1) == id(s2)

Answer (score 4):

Это значит, что копия создается в момент изменения, а не присваивания.

Comment: хм... интересно